# FileReader is not defined with Angular Server Side Rendering

Tags: c#, node.js, typescript, asp.net-core, angular8

I'm setting Server Side Rendering in a large webapp. It works well for page without FileReader instance. Do you know how can I make FileReader to work with SSR enable?

I found an NPM package for filereader. I installed and import it in server.ts import * as FileReader from 'filereader'; but I got no result from that.

I also added the filereader package in the whitelist of webpack.server.config.ts with no luck again.

I tried to replace FileReader with new Response(blob).text(); but in that case it is the Response which is undefined too.

I also tried window.FileReader() and global.FileReader() and no luck again.

This is the method with FileReader:

```
function blobToText(blob: any): Observable<string> {
  return new Observable<string>((observer: any) => {
        if (!blob) {
            observer.next("");
            observer.complete();
        } else {
          let reader = new FileReader(); // FileReader is not defined
            reader.onload = event => { 
                observer.next((<any>event.target).result);
                observer.complete();
            };
            reader.readAsText(blob); 
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the error message

> I got: ERROR { Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError:
>   FileReader is not defined ReferenceError: FileReader is not defined
>       at Observable._subscribe....

Comment: Some of the discussion here may be useful. https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/1692

Answer (score 3):

`FileReader` is a Web API; use `fs` object of Node instead, see [docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v9.x/api/fs.html).

Comment: how? Would you give me the line that explain it?

Comment: Impossible to use fs, I always got "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in."

Comment: Can you give me a step by step or even a working example on github please?

Answer (score 2):

```
function blobToText(blob: any): Observable<string> {
    return new Observable<string>((observer: any) => {
        if (!blob) {
            observer.next("");
            observer.complete();
        } else {
            if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
                observer.next(blob);
                observer.complete();
            } else {
                let reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = event => {
                    observer.next((<any>event.target).result);
                    observer.complete();
                };
                reader.readAsText(blob);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install "@types/node"

By this command

```
npm install --save @types/node
```

Then in your tsconfig.json add

```
"typeRoots": [
  "node_modules/@types"
]
```

If not work open your tsconfig.app.json file add to types section

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "module": "esNext",
    "types": ["node"] // add node here
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: It didn't solve the problem. FileReader always undefined. Futhermore, I added use import `{ readFileSync } from 'fs'; with observer.next(readFileSync(blob).toString);
            observer.complete();` and I got **"Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in..." **

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer comes too late but in case anybody else could run into this issue, this solution worked for me, when using **Angular 9**. So basically you need to **create a block of code that only gets executed when your application is on the browser** not in the server side:

```
//Import PLATFORM_ID and Inject from @angular/core
import { Component, OnInit, PLATFORM_ID, Inject } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-post',
  templateUrl: './new-post.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-post.component.scss']
})
export class NewPostComponent implements OnInit {

//Change the FileReader variable
reader; //before it was: reader: FileReader = new FileReader(); 

//Inject PLATFORM_ID as follow: 
    constructor(  @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: any,
                  private readonly activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
                  private readonly fileUploadService: FileUploadService) {
    }

     ngOnInit() {
     //Create a code block that only gets executed when it's loaded in the browser: 
        if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
          this.reader = new FileReader();
     }

}
```